# trying to check if git is up2date with remote

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to check a local git with its remote in a script.

My idea was to check it by "git -C ${GITPATH}/${GITNAME} fetch --dry-run".
If the local git branch is up2date with the remote git branch I get nothing back from the command.
If the local git branch is NOT up2date with the remote git branch I get information like these:

> c7104a4..3593140  testing    -> origin/testing

At this point I started to write an simple IF  for a check:

```
if [[ -z $(git -C ${GITPATH}/${GITNAME} fetch --dry-run) ]]
then
    echo "Up2Date"
else
    echo "Not Up2Date"
```

But in both situations, test git is up2date on the local system and test git is not up2date on the local system, I get a "Not Up2Date" like I get a text output from `it -C ${GITPATH}/${GITNAME} fetch --dry-run`.
But I get only a text output if the local git is really not up2date...

Any suggestions for this behavior?

thx in advance

Comment: run script with `bash -x` or do `set -x` before the commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command doesn't do what you think it's doing: `git fetch` will update *remote-tracking names*, not local branches, so if the remote-tracking name is all good but the local branch is behind, `git fetch` won't need to update anything, and as a result, you'll get the wrong information: a claim that you *are* up to date.  See further details below.

That aside, `git fetch`:

- prints most of its output to stderr, not stdout, so you would need to redirect its stderr to its stdout inside the subshell; and
- prints, at least potentially, other strings than the remote-tracking name updates, so the `-z` test might find nonzero length strings even if there are no remote-tracking name updates reported.

If you really do want to find out whether a *local* branch name's commit hash matches that of some name in some other Git, you should use one of these two methods:

1. Run `git fetch` *without* `--dry-run`, to bring in any new commits and update the local Git's remote-tracking names such as `origin/testing`, then use, e.g., `git rev-parse origin/testing`<sup>1</sup> to get the hash ID for the remote-tracking name; or
2. Use `git ls-remote` to get the hash ID for the branch name as it appears on the remote.

You can then compare this hash ID with the hash ID of the actual local branch.  If the two hash IDs match, the local branch matches the branch as seen in the other Git.  If not, it does not.

---

<sup>1</sup>For better reliability, use the full spelling of each name, so that in the (bad) case of someone using the same name as both branch name and tag name, Git won't resolve the shortened name in favor of the tag name.  That is, instead of:

```
REMOTE=origin
BRANCH=testing
git fetch $REMOTE
if test $(git rev-parse $BRANCH) != $(git rev-parse $REMOTE/$BRANCH); then
    echo out of sync
else
    echo in sync
fi
```

you would be better off making the test itself use:

```
test $(git rev-parse refs/heads/$BRANCH) != $(git rev-parse refs/remotes/$REMOTE/$BRANCH)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the piece of information I was looking for.